# How to specify common gradle properties in root gradle.build script

Tags: android, gradle

I have a large number of gradle modules I use to build my android applications and libraries. My application is decomposed into multiple java & C++ libraries. Each module might be a java library, or an APK project. For each module representing an APK, I have a `build.gradle` which specifies various `productFlavors` sections that control how to build them. Example:

```
   flavorDimensions "mode"

   productFlavors {
      arm {
         dimension "mode"
         externalNativeBuild {
            ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
         }
      }

      x86 {
         dimension "mode"
         externalNativeBuild {
            ndk { abiFilters "x86" }
         }
      }

      full {
         dimension "mode"
         externalNativeBuild {
            ndk { abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a" }
         }
      }
   }
```

What I'm trying to avoid is duplicating the above configuration in each leaf `build.gradle` that represents an APK output. How can I store the product flavors at the root level and somehow have those transitive to the leave `build.gradle` files so I do not need to duplicate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support library does something very similar, and you can [see their method here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/buildSrc) (in particular, [the `SupportLibraryPlugin`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/android/support/SupportLibraryPlugin.groovy)).

At a high level the strategy is to create a Gradle plugin in your `buildSrc` directory that you apply to each of your projects. This plugin will apply the common configuration.

Your plugin might look something like this:
**[project]/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/example/ConfigurationPlugin.groovy**

```
class ConfigurationPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        LibraryExtension library = project.extensions.findByType(LibraryExtension.class);

        library.flavorDimensions "mode"

        library.productFlavors {
            arm {
                dimension "mode"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
                }
            }

            x86 {
                dimension "mode"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndk { abiFilters "x86" }
                }
            }

            full {
                dimension "mode"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndk { abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a" }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**[project]/builSrc/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
}
```

Library module **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: ConfigurationPlugin

android {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When you do the 'apply plugin', how does gradle know that `ConfigurationPlugin` contents need to go under `android { ... }`?

Comment: When the plugin is applied (in the `apply()` method), we get the `android {}` configuration, which is a `LibraryExtension` class for Android libraries. That [`LibraryExtension`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.html) has all the properties of the `android {}` closure.

Comment: Also can I structure this so that my groovy code isn't at the root? For example, I'd like to store it in a sibling module (also with its java code) and use that from any other module. I can't get the apply plugin command to find it. Doesn't it need to be `apply plugin: 'com.example.ConfigurationPlugin'`?

Comment: If you don't want to use `buildSrc`, you can check out the full [Writing Custom Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) documentation for how to put it in a standalone project. If you put it in another module, you have to make sure to include that module in your buildscript dependencies (not your regular library dependencies).

Comment: I'm trying to do the separate module that I build with groovy code to do the common setup. However, how do you pull this into your root build.gradle via the `buildscript` block? This plugin should be built along with the normal code, I won't be prebuilding it or uploading it to a maven-like repository.

Comment: Yes, you would pull it in via the buildscript block. It is a buildscript dependency because it is affecting the Gradle model (and thus your buildscripts).

Comment: Great. So can the plugin module be built, as opposed to downloaded from a repo, prior to the main project modules being built? I'm not sure how to specify a plugin dependency in the `buildscript` block when that plugin has no jar file yet (it needs to compile it for me first)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference another Gradle project within your project using `':project-name'`, e.g. `compile ':pluginproject'`. You'll also want to update settings.gradle to include the other project. The project will be built when it is needed to apply the plugin.